# I need Laravel Query for Post list with details of user who created post and a flag which says if any post is liked by requesting user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am learning Laravel. I need your help for the following case.

I have created 3 tables names users, posts, post_likes. Each Table contains fields as mentioned below.

**1. users table**

-- id, username,profile_pic,email (id is the Primary key)

**2. posts table**

-- id, title, photo, user_id (Where id is primary key and user_id is pk of users table)

**3. post_likes table**

-- id, post_id, user_id (where id is the primary key and post_id is pk of  posts table and user_id is pk of users table)

Now, I need a list of all posts with all data in posts table, user details who created particular post and a flag for each post which says if the post is liked by the logged in user or not.

Please help me to write a query with using Laravel.

I have written following query:

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
                 ->leftJoin('post_likes', 'posts.id', '=', 'post_likes.post_id')
                 ->leftJoin('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                 ->select(DB::raw('posts.*,users.name,users.profile_pic, (CASE WHEN post_likes.user_id = \''.$request->user_id.'\' THEN "1" ELSE "0" END) as liked'))
                 ->orderBy('posts.id', 'desc')
                 ->get();
```

Which gives me following result:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": "8",
            "user_id": "59",
            "title": "This is test post from Rocky",
            "photo": "JyWhsvA57BDlCYLUpJksbmgFsoB1P.jpg",
            "name": "Green",
            "profile_pic": "jHAqnRWyVi1wl83m207Pc415Tgi.jpg",
            "liked": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "user_id": "9",
            "title": "This is test post from Ruby",
            "photo": "",
            "name": "Sandy",
            "profile_pic": "nRWyVi1wl83m207Pc415Tgi.jpg",
            "liked": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "user_id": "10",
            "title": "Let's hangout",
            "photo": "J54fctcGMsh6f5OC3DvWqISurO.jpg",
            "name": "Jhonty",
            "profile_pic": "E1N5qEVJPQ67YSyHo8MljQNvF.png",
            "liked": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "user_id": "10",
            "title": "Let's hangout",
            "photo": "J54fctcGMsh6f5OC3DvWqISurO.jpg",
            "name": "Jhonty",
            "profile_pic": "E1N5qEVJPQ67YSyHo8MljQNvF.png",
            "liked": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see I am receiving the post with id = 3 two times. I need it only once and in which like should be 1. Currently I am getting two entries in which one has likes= 0 and the other have like = 1 for the same post.

this happens when same post is liked by multiple users. Means post_likes table has entries as following

```
id     post_id    user_id

1      1           5
2      3           10
3      3           9
```

So based on this values I am getting the post with id 3 two times in result.

Please feel free to ask for any questions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about ````GROUP BY````? For example ````->groupBy('posts.id')````

Comment: That is returning one entry but the liked flag is coming 0 actually it should be 1 as that post id liked by that user.

Comment: By the time you are joining ````post_likes```` to your query you will get the same post multiple times. So I believe ````GROUP BY```` is a must. In my opinion you need to make a second query for the ````liked```` result. Except if someone gives a more sophisticated query solution.

Comment: What do you mean by second query? Can you give me example for my case?

Comment: ````SELECT COUNT(*) AS liked FROM post_likes WHERE post_id = 3 AND user_id = 10```` You make this query in laravel and you get the first (and only) row. Then if this row has ````->liked```` equal to 1 then the user has liked the post.

Comment: As a side note, your `DB::raw('posts.*,users.name,users.profile_pic, (CASE WHEN post_likes.user_id = \''.$request->user_id.'\' THEN "1" ELSE "0" END) as liked')` is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared statements instead `DB::raw('posts.*,users.name,users.profile_pic, (CASE WHEN post_likes.user_id = \'?\' THEN "1" ELSE "0" END) as liked', [$request->user_id])`

Comment: @kostas How will I merge the result of the query you have written with each row of the first query result (I mean post list)?

Comment: @ArunAS When I am trying the the way you suggested it is not giving me desired result. I mean liked is coming 0 always.

Comment: Why are you not using Eloquent relationships and queries to get this information? There are much simpler ways (on the code-writing side) to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

```php
// get posts
$posts = DB::table('posts')
                 ->leftJoin('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                 ->select(DB::raw('posts.*,users.name,users.profile_pic'))
                 ->orderBy('posts.id', 'desc')
                 ->get();

// make posts assosiative arrays
$posts = json_decode(json_encode($posts), true);

// for each post find if it's liked by the user
foreach ($posts as &$post) {
  $liked = DB::table('post_likes')
    ->select(DB::row('COUNT(*) AS liked'))
    ->where('post_id', '=', $post['id'])
    ->where('user_id', '=', $request->user_id)
    ->get()
    ->liked;

  $post['liked'] = $liked;
}
unset($post);
```